# Confusing SQL Query, Group By? Having?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

I have a relational database in SQL Server which I use to store Products, Competitor Companies and Competitor Prices. I regularly add new records to the Competitor Prices table rather than updating existing records so I can track prices changes over time.

I want to build a query which given a particular product, find the most recent price from each of the competitors. It is possible that each competitor doesn't have a price recorded.

Data Example

*tblCompetitorPrices*

```
+-----+----------+-------------+-----+----------+
|cp_id|product_id|competitor_id|price|date_added|
+-----+----------+-------------+-----+----------+
|1    |1         |3            |70.00|15-01-2014|
+-----+----------+-------------+-----+----------+
|2    |1         |4            |65.10|15-01-2014|
+-----+----------+-------------+-----+----------+
|3    |2         |3            |15.20|15-01-2014|
+-----+----------+-------------+-----+----------+
|4    |1         |3            |62.30|19-01-2014|
+-----+----------+-------------+-----+----------+
```

And I want the query to return...

```
+-----+----------+-------------+-----+----------+
|cp_id|product_id|competitor_id|price|date_added|
+-----+----------+-------------+-----+----------+
|4    |1         |3            |62.30|19-01-2014|
+-----+----------+-------------+-----+----------+
|2    |1         |4            |65.10|15-01-2014|
+-----+----------+-------------+-----+----------+
```

I can currently access all the prices for the product, but I'm not able to filter the results so only the most recent price for each competitor is shown - I'm really unsure...here is what I have so far....

```
SELECT cp_id, product_id, competitor_id, price, date_added 
FROM tblCompetitorPrices
WHERE product_id = '1' 
ORDER BY date_added DESC
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hmmmm, can you explain a little bit more about what you want? You currently can get 3 results but you only want 2? Is that it?

Comment: Over time more prices will be added from each competitor. To summarize the current prices I want to filter the results so that only the most recent price from each competitor is returned. Which means only returning on price for each competitor which the the most recent price added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you can also use `ROW_NUMBER()` which is a Window function that generates sequential number.

```
SELECT  cp_id,
        product_id,
        competitor_id,
        price,
        date_added
FROM    (
            SELECT  cp_id,
                    product_id,
                    competitor_id,
                    price,
                    date_added,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY competitor_id
                                        ORDER BY date_added DESC) rn
            FROM    tblCompetitorPrices
            WHERE   product_ID = 1
        ) a 
WHERE   a.rn = 1
```

This query can easily be modified to return latest record for each competitor in every product.

Comment: This query works better because it will return the most recent prices if they are on different dates! Brilliant answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
SELECT cp_id, product_id, competitor_id, price, date_added 
FROM tblCompetitorPrices
WHERE product_id = '1' AND date_added=( SELECT MAX(date_added) 
FROM tblCompetitorPrices
WHERE product_id = '1') 
ORDER BY date_added DESC
```

Comment: Hi Sajad, I get this error when running.."An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference."

Comment: Thats brilliant @Sajad Lfc- it works perfectly. Could you explain how that is working?

Comment: @Adam92 just added a condition in a subquery,where the subquery will give us the latest date where product id=1,this result of the subquery is the condition for the main query,that it should be the latest date matching a particular product id..!!

Comment: @Adam92:you said it works perfectly,then do you know what is an upvote for?, i think John give you a better answer,but altleast my answer worked for you,John's answer is an alternative,my answer is not wrong

Answer (score 0):

It took a while since I had to test the query myself, so yeah, here it is. Try it, it may help you even a bit with clause combinations. :)  It's shorter.

```
SELECT cp_id, product_id, competitor_id, price, MAX(date_added) as last_date 
FROM tblCompetitorPrices
WHERE product_id = '1' 
GROUP BY competitor_id
```